# Как вписать в mysqli запрос переменную?

Tags: php, mysqli

Не могу понять в какие кавычки нужно взять переменную  $title. Уже всевозможные варианты перебрал но проблема не исчезла..

Вот код:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$id = $_POST['id']
$q_all = "UPDATE `blog`.`categorie` SET `title` =  (text)'$title' WHERE `id` = (int)$id ";
$query_all = mysqli_query($db_conection, $q_all);
```

P.S $db_conection существует, просто проинклюдил файл с подключением выше.

Вот ошибка:
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in 
    Z:\home\vovblog\www\admin\admin.php on line 45

Comment: ну вот так же правильно у вас записано: "UPDATE `blog`.`categorie` SET `title` = '$title' WHERE `id` = $id" _(обратные кавычки местный парсер преобразовывает в жирный шрифт)_ А ещё надо после $id = $_POST['id'] поставить точку с запятой.

Comment: По поводу точки с запятой - спасибо, заработало, а вот запрос почемуто не осуществляется. Может еще в чем-то проблема..?

Comment: ну если выше в коде у вас есть подключение к бд, и вы уверены, что оно корректно, тогда возможно переменные пусты. Запишите запрос таким способом, и посмотрите на ответ бд: **$q_all = "UPDATE `blog`.`categorie` SET `title` = '$title' WHERE `id` = $id";
$query_all = mysqli_query($db_conection, $q_all) or die(mysqli_error($db_conection));**

Comment: Да, действительно, ошибка есть... Вот: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Нова назва категорії' WHERE `id` = (int)4' at line 1

Comment: а вы вот так записываете? WHERE  id = (int)$id Если да, то уберите скобки (int) и предыдущие (text)

Comment: Ни один из вышеперечисленных. Используйте подготовленные запросы и никогда не подставляйте данные, полученные от пользователя, напрямую в запрос

Comment: Ну.. не совсем полученные от "пользователь". Дело в том, что я решил написать блог это типа админ панель а именно форма изминения категории статьи..

Comment: Эдуард, спасибо все работает!

Comment: @Вова так-то не за что ) Мы разобрались только со sql-синтаксисом, а вот фильтрацию никто не отменял.   Прислушайтесь к совету из комментария выше, и почитайте про подготовленные запросы.

Answer (score -2):

можешь по старому

```
 $query_all = mysqli_query($db_conection, "UPDATE `blog`.`categorie` SET `title` = '".$title."' WHERE `id` = '".$id."' ");
```

короче так   set tittle = '".$title."'